Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference
Error showing in logcat after running quiz app
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference
you can click on the text to see an image of code 
NullpointerException occured in countdownTimer.start()
NullpointerException occured in countDownTimer.start()
i try to solve this error many times in a different ways but I couldn't please help in this regard.

Post the relevant code parts where you create and use CountDownTimer. BTW: Please format stacktraces and comments as code for readability (e.g. three backticks before and after the code ```.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Where are you creating your CountDownTimer? You may need to add a check that countDownTimer is not null in your onResume/onPause etc methods, in case onResume is executing before you have initialised countDownTimer.
E.g.
if (countDownTimer != null) {
    countDownTimer.start();
}

